# Fail2ban teamspeak failregex isue

Tags: fail2ban

can anybody help me solv this problem with failregex in my teamspeak.conf

teamspeak.conf

```
[INCLUDES]
before = common.conf

[Definition]
failregex = ^(.*)query from .* <HOST>:.* attempted to login with account "(.*)" and failed!$
        ^.*query from .* <HOST>:.* attempted to login with account.*

ignoreregex =
```

log output:

```
2019-10-24 08:29:35.710294|INFO    |Query         |   |query from 75785 62.216.206.7:62244 attempted to login with account "serveradmin" and failed!
2019-10-24 08:37:33.453525|INFO    |Query         |   |query from 75796 195.242.213.133:64290 attempted to login with account "serveradmin" and failed!
2019-10-24 08:57:55.560621|INFO    |Query         |   |query from 75823 195.242.213.133:64450 attempted to login with account "serveradmin" and failed!
2019-10-24 08:58:43.181434|INFO    |Query         |   |query from 75825 195.242.213.133:64452 attempted to login with account "serveradmin" and failed!
2019-10-24 08:58:47.488567|INFO    |Query         |   |query from 75826 195.242.213.133:64453 attempted to login with account "serveradmin" and failed!
2019-10-24 12:05:36.056572|INFO    |Query         |   |query from 76123 46.101.214.156:65367 attempted to login with account "serveradmin" and failed!
2019-10-24 12:17:47.239510|INFO    |Query         |   |query from 76224 46.101.231.209:65534 attempted to login with account "serveradmin" and failed!
2019-10-24 12:24:51.547201|INFO    |Query         |   |query from 76304 46.101.231.209:49254 attempted to login with account "serveradmin" and failed!
```

for some reason fail2ban faild to found this..ty

fail2ban log:

```
2019-10-24 14:24:31,034 fail2ban.jail           [12255]: INFO    Creating new jail 'teamspeak'
2019-10-24 14:24:31,034 fail2ban.jail           [12255]: INFO    Jail 'teamspeak' uses pyinotify {}
2019-10-24 14:24:31,036 fail2ban.jail           [12255]: INFO    Initiated 'pyinotify' backend
2019-10-24 14:24:31,038 fail2ban.filter         [12255]: INFO    Added logfile: '/home/ogpbot/OGP_User_Files/ts3/teamspeak3-server_linux_amd64/logs/ts3server_1.log' (pos = 5315034, hash = 9f92cd1a6d9ecaf2fe9d92ce17d2fe16d7baeeed)
2019-10-24 14:24:31,038 fail2ban.filter         [12255]: INFO    Added logfile: '/home/ogpbot/OGP_User_Files/ts3/teamspeak3-server_linux_amd64/logs/ts3server_0.log' (pos = 128742, hash = 3ebebf1d3196b0806f4751cfc52cd2e94a1a58f3)
2019-10-24 14:24:31,038 fail2ban.filter         [12255]: INFO      encoding: UTF-8
2019-10-24 14:24:31,038 fail2ban.filter         [12255]: INFO      maxRetry: 3
2019-10-24 14:24:31,039 fail2ban.filter         [12255]: INFO      findtime: 3600
2019-10-24 14:24:31,039 fail2ban.actions        [12255]: INFO      banTime: 3600
```

fail2ban jail status:

```
Status for the jail: teamspeak
|- Filter
|  |- Currently failed: 0
|  |- Total failed:     0
|  `- File list:        /home/ogpbot/OGP_User_Files/ts3/teamspeak3-server_linux_amd64/logs/ts3server_1.log /home/ogpbot/OGP_User_Files/ts3/teamspeak3-server_linux_amd64/logs/ts3server_0.log
`- Actions
   |- Currently banned: 0
   |- Total banned:     0
   `- Banned IP list:
```